# coredata importing sqlite but not saving new data Cocoa error 256

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

EDIT, // REASON FOR NOT SAVING>

so I put some nslog in my saveData (plese check in below code), after saving edited, and saved new data,
for the edited, is fine
but for the new,, I get>

```
Error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)
```

** Second Edit>
if I edit and save the first time, it saves fine the edited data, but shows error 256 for new data,

but if I try to save the edited data after having the 256 error (by trying to save new data), then the edited data shows error 256 when saving and doesnt get saved!!!!

Im importing some sqlitedb (the same that coredata generates but with some prepopulated tables)

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChildCare_v02.sqlite"];

    NSString *storePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ChildCare_v02"   ofType:@"sqlite"];

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ChildCare_v02.sqlite"]; //este es el que sirve!!! CREE ESTE

    NSLog(@"store URL %@", storeURL);

    // Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]) {
        NSLog(@"proceda aqui");
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ChildCare_v02"   ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"no existe todavia");
        NSLog(@"defalultStorePath %@", defaultStorePath);

        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:writableDBPath error:NULL];
            NSLog(@"storePath= %@", storePath);
        }
    }    

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]    initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType   configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}
```

it creates the new db fine, and populates it with the existing data, when I edit the data (prepopulated), in the app, it saves this data (checked in simulator document with sqlite manager, and going out and in again), but if I create a new entry, it shows in the table showing the data, but when I leave the app, and come back then this newly created entry is not there (and of course not in the sqlite new db)...

this is the code I use for saving edited data or newly created data,

```
-(IBAction)saveData
{
    if(editFlag==1)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(ChildCare_v01AppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [request setEntity:entity];

        editEmp.namemployee = tfName.text;
        editEmp.surname = tfSurname.text;
        editEmp.email = tfEmail.text;
        //editEmp.phone = tfPhone.text;
        editEmp.mobile = tfMobile.text;

        editEmp.category=tfCategory.text;

        NSLog(@"salvado editado"); //saving FINE!!!!        

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error])
        { NSLog(@"Error %@",[error localizedDescription]); } 
        //[context release];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

    }
    else{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(ChildCare_v01AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        Employee *employee = (Employee*)[NSEntityDescription
                                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" 
                                         inManagedObjectContext:context];
        employee.namemployee = tfName.text;
        employee.surname = tfSurname.text;
        employee.email = tfEmail.text;
        //employee.phone=tfPhone.text;
        employee.mobile = tfMobile.text;    
        employee.category=tfCategory.text;

        NSLog(@"salvado nuevo"); ///HERE THE ERROR!! COCOA ERROR 256!!!!    

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            // handle error
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

    }
}
```

- so its it possible to save the newly created data?? why is not working? why only saves edits? and no new data?, please help me to achieve this, thanks a lot!

Comment: dump the userInfo of the error when there is an error. `NSLog(@"Error %@ [%@]",[error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);` This will give you more info about the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to try:
1. Make sure the managedObjectContext has a non-null value before you save to it.
2. Is your db initialization code re-installing the original db (thereby losing your changes)?
Good luck.

Comment: hi, thank you for responding, I have to check for number 1, will edit when I check, as for 2, the original db is not reinstalling, because the changes I make when editing, are saved (checked this using sqlite manager, in the original one the original data stays the same, but in the simulator folder, the sqlite, saves the data for that edit)

Comment: number 1, the "scratch pad is not empty" as I can see the data in the table after hitting save... but when leaving the app, the data is not there anymore;

Comment: In your persistenStoreCoordinator method, isn't this code called each time?  Doesn't that overwrite the db?
if (defaultStorePath) {
  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:writableDBPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"storePath= %@", storePath);
  }
 }

Comment: hi, tnx, I dont understand how the db is getting overwritten, because if I edit the data loaded (from the sqlite prepopulated file), this edited data after saved, gets saved in the coredata sqlite (in the simulator and in the phone), checked in sqlite manager and going out and in the app, is there,,,but if I create a new entry, this new entry doesn't get saved..

Comment: Ok, I see that the overwrite code is inside the if block.  Sorry about that.    How do you know that the insert is failing?  Do you see an error message, or is it just absent from the results?  What does your query look like?  Are you clearing the cache before executing the fetchRequest?

Comment: no error message, the "saved" (not saving really for new entries) data, shows in the table, but when I leave the app, this data is not saved really, also is not showing in sqlite manager in the document view of course,

Comment: Is your Employee class a sub-class of NSManagedObject?     
How are the members of that class declared (@synthesize, @dynamic, or something else?)